# What is the difference between SUID file permission and ACL?

Tags: permissions, acl, suid

What is the difference between SUID and ACL file permission? Also, when should I use either?

Comment: What’s the difference between a cat and a car?  Or between a cat and a vat?  What I’m getting at is: How do you think SUID and ACL file permission are even comparable?  If you don’t understand what they are,  this question is a very peculiar starting point for learning.

Comment: There is a minor overlap between POSIX ACLs (which can define how acls are inherited) and setgid directories, but that’s about as much as I can guess they’re related.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have much to do with each other, although both loosely concern file permissions.

**SUID (Set User ID)** is a permission that can be set on an executable file so that it is run with the privileges of the file's owner, not with the privileges of the user invoking the command. It is done via the command `chmod u+s myfile`.

**ACL (Access Control Lists)** is the way to give more fine-grained permissions to files, compared to the Discretionary Access Control (`rwx` permissions to user, group, and other) used as a default in Linux systems. They are set using the `setfacl` command.

You very rarely set SUID on a file on your own as it may cause security vulnerabilities. (Think about a shell with SUID root...) ACLs, on the other hand, are used often.

Answer (score -3):

File permission bits have been around since the beginning. See `man -a chmod`.

File permission bits divide the population into Owner, Group, World (same UID, same GID, everyone else). The "same" comparisons compare, for example, the UID of the process accessing a file to the file's UID.

This was insufficient for modern requirements, and other operating systems had come up with better ideas (Access Control Lists), and computers had gotten faster*, and ACLs were added to Linux, supplementing, not replacing, File Permission Bits. `man setfacl` will explain how ACLs work.

* File Permission Bits are in the `inode`, which is readily available when dealing with a file. Access Control Lists require following lists, running code, ... It made a difference on old, low clock speed computers, which is where Unix/Linux was born.
"If it works, don't fix it".